# Can't find py_module_initializer! when building python module in rust

Tags: python-2.7, rust, cpython, toml

Very new to Rust.

I'm trying to build a python module in Rust using rust-cypthon. Currently, I can access cpython types but can't call py_module_initializer! which I believe is required to make the module run in python.

When compiling the code, changing the extension to .so and putting the file in with my python scripts and importing, I get this error:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initpyext_rust_onboard)
```

Cargo.toml

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
csv = "1.1.1"
serde = "1.0.99"
serde_derive="1.0"
serde_json= "1.0"
serde_yaml = "0.7.1"

[dependencies.cpython]
version = '0.3.0'
default-features = false
features = ["python27-sys", "extension-module-2-7"]
```

Dependencies imported to lib.rs

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_derive;

#[macro_use]extern crate cpython;


use std::fs::File;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::borrow::Cow;
use std::error::Error;
use cpython::{Python, PyObject, PyResult, PyString, PyFloat};
use csv::DeserializeRecordsIter;
```

Answer (score 2):

> When compiling the code, changing the extension to `.so` and putting the file in with my python scripts

What are you renaming it from? The [rust-cpython](https://github.com/dgrunwald/rust-cpython) documentation says

> On Mac OS, you will need to rename the output from `*.dylib` to `*.so`. On Windows, you will need to rename the output from `*.dll` to `*.pyd`.

and on Linux you shouldn't be renaming anything.

The problem is probably that you are not actually building a shared object. You have

> ```
> [lib]
> crate-type = ["dylib"]
> ```

but the [rust-cpython](https://github.com/dgrunwald/rust-cpython) readme says

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

Mind the `c`! `cdylib` and `dylib` are different things in rust.

Comment: I've changed it from a dylib file to a .so file as am on Mac. 
I've changed dylib to cdylib and changed features to ```features = ["python27-sys", "extension-module-2-7"]``` - now it will compile but I still can't access py_module_initialiser!

Comment: Edit: Realised I have access to the macro now but my IDE was ignoring it. Cheers for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`cpython` homepage](https://github.com/dgrunwald/rust-cpython#example-library-with-python-bindings), you need to enable the `extension-module` module feature, so try with:

```
[dependencies.cpython]
version = '0.3.0'
default-features = false
features = ["python27-sys", "extension-module-2-7"]
```